# Can I make a button in Django template to redirect a user to a specific Facebook Messenger account?

Tags: python, django

When the User clicks the button, Django must automatically send a message to a specific account in Facebook Messenger. Is that possible? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/send-api/

Answer (score 0):

welcome to SO, when asking a question please post the code you have tried. Also learn to ask a better question [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). With that said you can use a JS trigger on button click. I copied a snippet to send message from [geeks for geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/send-message-to-fb-friend-using-python/)

template.html

```
<button type="button" onclick="sendMessage()">Send Message</button>

<script>
const sendMessage(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'your-api-url',
        headers: {'X-CSRFToken': token},
        success: (e) => {
            alert("message has been sent");
        }
        error: (e) => {
            alert("something went wrong")
        }
    )}
}
</script>
```

views.py

```
import fbchat 

def send_message(request):

    username = "username"
    client = fbchat.Client(username, "password") 
    no_of_friends = 10 
    for i in range(no_of_friends): 
        name = "friend name" 
        friends = client.searchForUsers(name)  # return a list of names 
        friend = friends[0] 
        msg = "message"
        sent = client.sendMessage(msg, thread_id=friend.uid) 
        if sent: 
            print("Message sent successfully!")
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('send-message', views.send_message),
]
```